# How to apply ng-repeat on the objects within an array

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, single-page-application

I am working on a quiz web project. Which is **SPA** based application using angularjs, Node.js, mongodb. I stored the Object of users in mongodb like this...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac11e238172b601087a6920"), "userid" : "lucy", "password" : "$2a$10$/o5ioD82//x5gWzweWQNI.8bBHSxEEj3AnqWXgoQXSltP.y5NFgUi", "questions" : [ { "qstn" : "b", "opt1" : "b", "opt2" : "b", "opt3" : "b", "opt4" : "b", "ans" : "b" }, { "qstn" : "j", "opt1" : "j", "opt2" : "j", "opt3" : "j", "opt4" : "j", "ans" : "j" }, { "qstn" : "hhhh", "opt1" : "hh", "opt2" : "hh", "opt3" : "hh", "opt4" : "hh", "ans" : "hh" } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ac11e238172b601087a6920"), "userid" : "mani", "password" : "$2a$10$mGztF/S7hXyympOeunTiKOclTAKaTgBgzAkbsxIssFazwHxSq54um", "questions" : [ { "qstn" : "a", "opt1" : "b", "opt2" : "a", "opt3" : "a", "opt4" : "a", "ans" : "a" }, { "qstn" : "jj", "opt1" : "jj", "opt2" : "jj", "opt3" : "jj", "opt4" : "jj", "ans" : "jj" }, { "qstn" : "hhhh", "opt1" : "hh", "opt2" : "hh", "opt3" : "hh", "opt4" : "hh", "ans" : "hh" } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

And when I queried

```
fetchQuestions(request,response){
    User.find({},function(err,user){
        console.log(user);
    }).select('questions -_id').limit(10);
}
```

I got this result on server console

```
[ 
 { questions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
 { questions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
]
```

my test.html where I want to print questions with its options

```
<div>
<h1>{{qstn}}</h1>
<input type="checkbox">
<h1 ng-repeat="">{{opt1}}</h1><br>
<input type="checkbox">
<h1 ng-repeat="">{{opt2}}</h1><br>
<input type="checkbox">
<h1 ng-repeat="">{{opt3}}</h1><br>
<input type="checkbox">
<h1 ng-repeat="">{{opt4}}</h1>
```

any idea how to print these questions inside the array on the web page
How to apply **ng-repeat** to print the questions with its options

Comment: Add another ng-repeat inside to loop through the object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and I would say "should" a few things in your code.

1- On backend side. You should use `User.find({},{ questions: 1},function(err,user){..`

This will return you a document containing `_id` and `questions` property only.

Now when you've successfully received this data on frontend, to show the questions

you should try rendering this way

```
<div ng-repeat="data in response">      
  <div ng-repeat="qustion in data.questions">
    <h1>{{qstn}}</h1>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h1 >{{opt1}}</h1><br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h1>{{opt2}}</h1><br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h1 >{{opt3}}</h1><br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <h1 >{{opt4}}</h1>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: I would have answered more precisely if you'd have shown you `controller` code too.

Comment: Anyways, consider accepting this answer if this was helpful

Comment: sir could I use local storage of the browser to store the coming object and `[ 
 { questions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
 { questions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
]` and fetch out one by one. It would be a right way or not???

Answer (score 1):

you can use in ng-repeat as:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in users.questions">      
  <div ng-repeat="q in question">
   <h1>{{q.qstn}}</h1>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <h1 >{{q.opt1}}</h1><br>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <h1>{{q.opt2}}</h1><br>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <h1>{{q.opt3}}</h1><br>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <h1 >{{q.opt4}}</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```